# Auto height for iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I wanted to iframe/embed a page from my own server and set the height to auto. I have done some research and it turns out that I can't make the height to auto. I am trying to achieve something like this: http://themeforest.net/item/king-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/12354623

This is what I tried so far:

HTML:

```
<iframe class="forum-embed" src="forum/index.php"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
.forum-embed {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    border: none;
}
```

PS: Themeforest also uses iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the browser window/document height and then set the iframe height.

if you are using jquery you can do something like this:

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

If you view source on the link that you have posted for themeforest, you can see how they do it.. From their source....

```
  //function to fix height of iframe!
  var calcHeight = function() {
    var headerDimensions = $('.preview__header').height();
    $('.full-screen-preview__frame').height($(window).height() - headerDimensions);
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    calcHeight();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    calcHeight();
  }).load(function() {
    calcHeight();
  });
```

Comment: It would really help me if you could maybe add a Snippet or display the html part. Because I am not that familiar with javascript and jquery. I thank very, very much :)

Comment: post your html.. based on the example you had posted, the answer i gave works.. seems like your usecase/code is different

Comment: you were missing the jquery library.. add this in your html.. `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>` and it should work

Comment: I could swear there are security issues of doing this cross domain.  I remember trying to do this couple years back and it was a HUGE issue.  The problem is the inside iframe doesn't have to be on the same domain as the outside parent, and having cross domain JS function is going to take some work.

Comment: Still not working unfortunately.. look now. I added the Query, not working in the Snippet neither in my local server. https://jsfiddle.net/sc89hjjn/1/embedded/result/

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about. I can see it occupying the full screen height.

Comment: in the snippet, http://prntscr.com/8rkoom and at my local website: http://prntscr.com/8rkp7a

Comment: okay.. you are talking about the scrollbars.. just hide them.. use this in your css `body {overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: isn't working on the snippet neither on my local server, https://jsfiddle.net/sc89hjjn/2/embedded/result/